# Kafka create topic by using TopicCommand

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I want to creat a topic by using java. There are my codes.

```
String s = "--topic pt8 --create --zookeeper 10.11.6.52:2181 --replica-assignment 7";
String[] args2 = s.split(" ");
TopicCommand.main(args2);
```

But there is an error:

> [ZkClient-EventThread-14-10.11.6.52:2181] INFO  o.I.z.ZkEventThread - Starting ZkClient event thread.
>
> [main] INFO  o.I.z.ZkClient - Waiting for keeper state SyncConnected
>   [main-EventThread] INFO  o.I.z.ZkClient - zookeeper state changed
>   (SyncConnected)
>
> Error while executing topic command :
>   java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
>
> [ZkClient-EventThread-14-10.11.6.52:2181] INFO  o.I.z.ZkEventThread -
>   Terminate ZkClient event thread.

`--list --zookeeper 10.11.6.52:2181` can get results.
`--delete --zookeeper 10.11.6.52:2181 --topic pt7` gets `Error while executing topic command : null`.

My pom.xml：

```
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
        <version>0.10.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Using Admin：

```
ZkClient  zkClient = new ZkClient("10.11.6.52:2181", 30000, 30000, ZKStringSerializer$.MODULE$);
ZkUtils zkUtils = ZkUtils.apply(zkClient, false);
AdminUtils.createTopic(zkUtils, "pt8", 1, 1, new Properties(), RackAwareMode.Disabled$.MODULE$);
```

ERROR：

> Exception in thread "main" kafka.admin.AdminOperationException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Comment: Is Zookeeper running?

Comment: I am using a clustered zookeeper IP. `--list --zookeeper 10.11.6.52:2181` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a shell command and trying to execute it from JAVA, use the KAFKA Admin client API, which should work with Kafka 0.11+.

Here is a code snippet:

```
void setUpKafkaTopics(KafkaAdminClient kafkaAdminClient) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
  final Map<String, Integer> topics = new HashMap<>();
  topics.put(topicName, numOfPartitions);
  kafkaAdminClient.createTopics(topics, getTopicConfig(), replicationFactor);
}


Map<String, String> getTopicConfig() {
  Map<String, String> topicConfiguration = new HashMap<>();
  topicConfiguration.put(TopicConfig.UNCLEAN_LEADER_ELECTION_ENABLE_CONFIG,
     Boolean.FALSE.toString());
  topicConfiguration.put(TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_CONFIG,
     TopicConfig.CLEANUP_POLICY_DELETE);
  topicConfiguration.put(TopicConfig.COMPRESSION_TYPE_CONFIG,
     KAFKA_TOPIC_COMPRESSION_TYPE);
  topicConfiguration.put(TopicConfig.MIN_IN_SYNC_REPLICAS_CONFIG,
     KAFKA_TOPIC_MIN_IN_SYNC_REPLICAS.toString()); 
  topicConfiguration.put(TopicConfig.RETENTION_MS_CONFIG,
     KAFKA_TOPIC_RETENTION_MS.toString()); 
  return topicConfiguration;
}
```

Comment: I don't think that is available with `0.10.2.1` dependency being used

Comment: Oh yes, sorry about that i just saw that u r using `0.10.2.1`, Admin clients came in `0.11.x`

Comment: Note: this isn't "my" question